# Need to dynamically load drop down list after they select a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

A user has a random drop down list they select a value. Then I need to have another dropdown list depending on the value they choice. The user will have a drop down list for the item they will want to perform an action on then I have another dropdown list for what action they want to do with the item they picked. Is there anyway with PHP or javascript I can dynamically load the values for the second dropdown list after they choice an something from the first dropdown??? here is an min example...this is the first dropdown.:

```
<label for="mydropdown" datalabel="mydropdown">Country:</label>    
<select name="mydropdown">
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="Other">Not Listed</option>
</select>
```

Then when they select a value I am trying to do an ajax call with the value they choice

```
    $("#select_item_chosen").change(function() {
            var el = $(this);
          console.log(el.val());
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "dropdownlist",
                data: 'csrf_token=' + $('meta[name=csrf-token-
  value]').attr('content') +'&Selectedcampaign_id=' + el.val(),
                success: function (response) {
                    var jsonResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

Then I need to load another dropdown list with depending on what they choice but I don't know what to do...do I reload the page?

Here is what i am sending back with PHP

```
public function actionDropdownlist (){
        $openListFieldAction = new CampaignOpenActionListField();

        if(isset($_POST['Selectedcampaign_id'])) {
            $postCampaign = $_POST['Selectedcampaign_id'];

            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->compare('campaign_id', $postCampaign);
            $criteria->compare('customer_id', (int)Yii::app()->customer->getId());
            $ajaxCampaign = Campaign::model()->find($criteria);

            $openListFieldAction->campaign_id = $ajaxCampaign->campaign_id;
            $openListFieldAction->list_id = $ajaxCampaign->list_id;
            $openListFieldActionOptions = $openListFieldAction->getTextFieldsAsDropDownOptions();
            echo json_encode(array("openListFieldActionOptions"=>$openListFieldActionOptions));
        }
    }
```

when i console log my jsonreponse this is what the console shows me:

```
Object {openListFieldActionOptions: Object}
openListFieldActionOptions
:
Object
288880
:
"FOFO"
__proto__
:
Object
constructor
:
function Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
function toLocaleString()
toString
:
function toString()
valueOf
:
function valueOf()
__defineGetter__
:
function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
function __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__
:
function __proto__()
set __proto__
:
function __proto__()
__proto__
:
Object
constructor
:
function Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
function toLocaleString()
toString
:
function toString()
valueOf
:
function valueOf()
__defineGetter__
:
function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
function __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__
:
function __proto__()
set __proto__
:
function __proto__()
```

Comment: So have you coded the PHP script you are referencing in `url: "create",`???

Comment: If you have the response array in json format, then you can loop through it and create a new element using javascript/jquery

Comment: well.. if you get the response in json, can't you do something like `$.each(jsonResponse, function(k,v){ $('#mydropdown').append(v); }); `

Comment: Okay I updated my responce with what I am doing in the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just work with your ajax result:

```
 success: function (response) {
    var jsonResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
    //process here
 }
```

But i am not recommended that way, instead of it use [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) transpiler:

```
$("#select_item_chosen").change(async function() {
   showEl(this);

   let response = await callAjax();

   let jsonResponse = $.parseJSON(response);

   renderDropDown(jsonResponce,$('body'));
}

function callAjax(){
  return $.ajax({});
 }

function showEl(el){
  var el = $(el);
  console.log(el.val());
 }

function renderDropDown(data,target){
  var select = $('<select>');
  data.forEach(x=>{
    var option = $('<option>',{value:x.value});
    option.html(x.text);
    select.append(option);
  });
  target.append(select);
 }
```

Comment: idk this looks so complicated, what is the simplist way to load a drop down list from json results

Comment: `$.post('url',data,x=>renderDropDown(x,$('body')))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one good example of what you are trying to accomplish. And I think this matches exactly what you are looking for

[Jquery-Value-Dependet-Dropdowns](http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/)